# I am trying to make a code where the number you put in, it prints that number as many time as you put it in

Tags: python

for example if I put in 5 it prints 5 5 5 5 5, and if I put in 2 it prints 2 2

there is no errors because I put in print(number * number) but then I realized that it just prints 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying an integer with another integer. So probably it will result in another integer. In order to print it n times the number n. You have to convert n to a string and you can multiply it with the integer n. Or else you print it in a loop.

```
print(*[n for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop:

```
number = 2
for x in range(0, number):
   print(number , end =" ")
```

Comment: this will have newline at the end of each output. use `print(number , end =" ") ` if you wanna loop through range.